# How to set the image resource of a dynamic imageview using multiple buttons

Tags: android, button, android-imageview

Hi I'm new to programming and android development. I'm working on a project and hoping someone can help me.

I have two activities one is MonthSelect, it contains buttons one for each month of the year. the other activity is QuoteDisplay, it contains a dynamic ImageView, array list of images and a swipe gesture detector.

I'm trying to make each button open the imageview on a different image from the array list and then allow me to scroll through the images as normal using swipe gestures.

For example if the February button is pressed the imageview displays the first image of February and then i can swipe left to the second image in February. Or if the May button is pressed the imageview displays the first image of May and allows me to scrolls through images as I please.

Iv tried using intents with different info in each to make then unique I read it somewhere saying that would work but it hasn't the activity will keep opening the same image. Unfortunately I honestly don't know any other methods as I am only and learning thought this would be a simply task to figure out.

I have included a simplified version of the code if anyone can help I'd appreciate it very much.

MonthSelect class

```
public class MonthSelect extends Activity {

    //ImageView images;
    //ImageView imagesTest;
    Button jan;
    Button feb;
    Button march;
    Button april;
    Button may;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.month_select);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


        findViewById(R.id.januaryButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.februaryButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.marchButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.aprilButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.mayButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

    }


    final OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //images = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.monthImageDisplay);
            //imagesTest = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagesTest);
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.januaryButton:

                Intent janIntent = new Intent(MonthSelect.this,MonthDisplay.class);
                //testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"January", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.februaryButton:       

                //testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "February", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.marchButton:

                //testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "March", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                break;

            case R.id.aprilButton:

                //testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "April", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.mayButton:
                //testing to see if pressed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "May", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            }//switch


        }//onClick

    };//buttonClickListener

}
```

QuoteDisplay

```
public class QuoteDisplay extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    RelativeLayout r1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    GestureDetector detector;


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DDD");
    String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    int parseStrDate = Integer.parseInt(strDate);
    int imageArrayCorrection = (parseStrDate -1);
    private int currentImage = imageArrayCorrection;



    //list of images
    public int[] imageList = 
        {R.drawable.j_1, R.drawable.j_2, R.drawable.j_3, R.drawable.j_4,
            R.drawable.j_5, R.drawable.j_6, R.drawable.j_7, R.drawable.j_8,
            R.drawable.j_9, R.drawable.j_10, R.drawable.j_11, R.drawable.j_12,
            R.drawable.j_13, R.drawable.j_14, R.drawable.j_15, R.drawable.j_16,
            R.drawable.j_17, R.drawable.j_18, R.drawable.j_19, R.drawable.j_20,
            R.drawable.j_21, R.drawable.j_22, R.drawable.j_23, R.drawable.j_24,
            R.drawable.j_25, R.drawable.j_26, R.drawable.j_27, R.drawable.j_28,
            R.drawable.j_29, R.drawable.j_30, R.drawable.j_31, 

            R.drawable.f_1, R.drawable.f_2, R.drawable.f_3, R.drawable.f_4, 
            R.drawable.f_5, R.drawable.f_6, R.drawable.f_7, R.drawable.f_8,
            R.drawable.f_9, R.drawable.f_10, R.drawable.f_11, R.drawable.f_12,
            R.drawable.f_13, R.drawable.f_14, R.drawable.f_15, R.drawable.f_16,
            R.drawable.f_17, R.drawable.f_18, R.drawable.f_19, R.drawable.f_20,
            R.drawable.f_21, R.drawable.f_22, R.drawable.f_23, R.drawable.f_24,
            R.drawable.f_25, R.drawable.f_26, R.drawable.f_27, R.drawable.f_28,


            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quote_display);
        detector = new GestureDetector(this, this);


       imageView();

    }//onCreate



    //Dynamic ImageView 
    protected void imageView(){
        r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.r1);
        imageView = new ImageView (this);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageList[imageArrayCorrection]);

    //Setting the parameters of the relative layout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (int)LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        r1.addView(imageView);
    }//imageView




    //registering TouchEvent with GerstureDetector
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override//Swipe gestures for left and right
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        float sensitivity = 50;
        //swipe left check
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX()>sensitivity){
            //increase counter to move to the next image
            currentImage++;
            currentImage = (currentImage + imageList.length)%imageList.length;
            imageView.setImageResource(imageList[currentImage]);
            //testing Fling Gesture
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<- Fling Gesture Left", 100).show();
            return true;
        }
        //swipe right check
        if(e2.getX() - e1.getX()>sensitivity){
            //decrease counter to go back to an image
            currentImage--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + imageList.length)%imageList.length;
            imageView.setImageResource(imageList[currentImage]);
            //testing Fling Gesture
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fling Gesture Right ->", 100).show();

        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make 12 int-Arrays with Picture-paths for each month. 
In MonthSelect you put on your Intent an item. You can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) how to do it.
When a  Button is pressed, you create a new Intent. Depending on which Month was selected you put the right Extra to this Intent.
For example for january:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MonthSelect.this,MonthDisplay.class); 
 //...
intent.putExtra("Month", 1);   // '1' because January is the first Month
```

Then in the QuoteDisplay's onCreate Method you store the Intent-Item called "Month" on another attribute:

```
int selectedMonth = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Month");
```

Now you know the selected Month and can use the right Picture-Array for your ImageView.